# npm WARN EPEERINVALID react-bootstrap-daterangepicker@1.0.6 requires a peer of jquery@^1.11.3 but none was installed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to build a react.js and webpack project.

when I go into project directory and do `npm install` I get this warning

```
npm WARN EPEERINVALID react-bootstrap-daterangepicker@1.0.6 
requires a peer of jquery@^1.11.3 but none was installed.
```

In the package.json I can see that jquery has been defined.

```
{
  "myapp": {
    "name": "foo",
    "rootPath": "./dist",
    "proxies": [
      {
        "from": "/bar",
        "to": "http://server"
      }
    ]
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register,jsx:test/compiler.js --require ./test/test_helper.js 'test/**/*.@(js|jsx)'",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.25",
    "babel-eslint": "^4.1.3",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "chai": "^3.4.1",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "eslint": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.5.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.2",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jsdom": "^7.0.2",
    "mocha": "^2.3.4",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.3",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^2.1.5",
    "sass-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-bundle-size-analyzer": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "c3": "^0.4.11-rc4",
    "d3": "^3.5.6",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.10",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.10",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "^1.1.0",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs": "^1.1.0",
    "history": "^1.12.5",
    "immutable": "^3.7.5",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "numeraljs": "^1.5.6",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.1",
    "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^3.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.2",
    "redux-immutablejs": "0.0.7",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Or should I really include 2 jquery versions in a single package.json?

When I use my application the date picker throws the following error message ( in the developer tools console)

```
Uncaught TypeError: $this.$picker.daterangepicker is not a function
```

Comment: Does react-bootstrap-daterangepicker fail or error if you used your `2.1.4` version? If not then your fine as is.

Comment: yes, nothing happens when i click on the date picker

Comment: No errors from jquery?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $this.$picker.daterangepicker is not a function`

Comment: seems a github issue for this pending.. [here](https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/51)

Comment: are there any known work-arounds? the same code is working for some of my colleagues... although they don't understand why it works for them. There must be something which avoids the issue

Comment: they probably have different libraries installed in their node_modules. Might be useful to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of troubleshooting. I was able to resolve this error

The problem is two folds

The issue `Uncaught TypeError: $this.$picker.daterangepicker is not a function` is a known issue. and has been documented here

https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/42

The problem with my code was that I was using a "^" behind my version so even though my package.json had specified 1.0.1 it was picking up 1.0.6 because of the ^

when I removed the ^ and cleaned the npm cache, I was able to download the right version and that resolved the problem.